# display:inline-block and overflow:hidden leading to different vertical alignment

Tags: html

The following code renders differently in different browsers
(IE = FF = higher than baseline, Chrome = on baseline).

1. Whose fault is it? Where should I file a bug report?
2. Do you know a way how to get this solved cross-browser. If I change vertical-alignment, I get it to work in some browsers, but not the others.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .a {
            display: inline-block;
            overflow: hidden;
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    baseline__<div class="a">test</div>__baseline
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T2vQj/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems Chrome is in error. The [CSS 2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) says

> The baseline of an 'inline-block' is the baseline of its last line box
>   in the normal flow, unless it has either no in-flow line boxes or if
>   its 'overflow' property has a computed value other than 'visible', in
>   which case the baseline is the bottom margin edge.

Since the overflow property computes to something other than 'visible' the inline-block's baseline is the bottom margin edge, which sits on the baseline of the containing line box, and therefore must raise up the contained text to allow space for the descenders of that text.

Answer (score 8):

Yes. You need to do these:

1. Remove the style `overflow: hidden;`. This is not needed here. You need this only when you give a `width` or `text-overflow: ellipsis;`.
2. Add `vertical-align: bottom;`. The vertical alignment of the text will change when the display is changed from `inline` to `inline-block`.

Comment: 1. I published a minimal working example. I left everything out that is not needed to reproduce the behavior I intended to show. 2. No, vertical-align leads to different results in different browsers, as described in the original posting.

Comment: Yes. Each browser handles the default value of `inline-block` in them.

Answer (score -2):

Try This

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .a {
            display: inline; 
            overflow: hidden;
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    baseline__<div class="a">test</div>__baseline
</body>
</html>
```